# PivotTable showing the Top 5 Sales Representatives per Month

Tags: excel, pivot-table, spreadsheet

I have an Excel data that shows the Sales of each of the Sales Reps. So I want to see the total for each rep per month which is easily doable with a PivotTable. Now I want the Pivot Table to only show the Top 5 per month so say I have 2 months in the coverage, I will see 10 names in total.

The Top filter in Pivot Tables computes for the Top for the entire data set and not for each category. Or am I missing something? Is it possible?

Thanks a lot for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a measure if you connect your data to the datemodel and use PowerPivot

[Rigth click on table to add Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY4Ft.png)

That will enable you to use DAX i Excel (used in Power BI) And by using DAX you can make a top 5 per categori

inspiration: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filtering-the-top-3-products-for-each-category-in-power-bi/